# Как привязать один select к другому select в javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня проблема. Есть два выпадающих списка.
В одном автомобили(марка), в другом модель.
Как сделать чтобы при выборе Ауди появлялся выпадающий список только моделей ауди, а при выборе Мерседес соответственно модели под мерседес. И чтобы в первом выпадающем списке если выбрана "марка автомобиля", то второй выпадающий список (с моделями) не появляется до тех пор пока не выберешь ауди или мерседес.
Хелп.

Оч желательно чтобы без сторонних библиотек или без них не обойтись?
Скрин прилагаю.

Comment: надо повесить обработчик `change` на первый список, смотреть, что было выбрано и заполнять второй список в зависимости от того, что выбрано - никаких сторонних библиотек для этого не нужно - голый javascript

Comment: спасибо большое, а где можно почитать про этот обработчик change? я новенький в этой теме, слабо разбираюсь.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp, https://www.techiedelight.com/get-selected-value-dropdown-javascript-onchange/ (смотрите пример голого javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const trademarks = ['Audi', 'ВАЗ'];
const models = [
  ['Q7'],
  ['Kalina', 'Priora']
];
const fill = (id, options) => {
  const sel = document.getElementById(id), def = 0;
  sel.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = options[i];
    if (i === def) {
      opt.selectedIndex = i;
    }
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }

  return def;
};

fill('model', models[fill('trademark', trademarks)]);
```

```html
<select id="trademark" onchange="fill('model', models[this.selectedIndex])"></select>
<select id="model"></select>
```